# Copying group of folders, first in line get's it's contents spilled in the open

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a group of folders which have various files inside them from one place to a single folder elsewhere. I want to bind said folder group to a variable.

```
param(
  $folders=('../folder1','../folder2')
)

Copy-Item -Path $folders -Destination '../folder3' -Recurse -Force;
```

This works, however, inside folder3, folder1's contents are spilled out, while folder2's contents are placed in a folder of the same name just like intended.

I need them both to be copied intact, if I switch their places then `folder2` gets the same treatment. It's like the script does not read the first folder in line in same way as the others. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
Managed to find a work-around by running additional command to create a folder inside "folder3" named same as first in line folder before copying. Script then places the files inside that folder correctly. Still rather messy, I wonder if it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop

```
foreach($folder in $folders){
    Copy-Item -Path $folder -Destination '../folder3'-Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: Sadly didn't work. It still spills out the contents of "folder1" out.

Comment: Can not reproduce this. Check the folder paths in $folders

Comment: Paths are correct, it finds the right files, however it does not copy them in orderly faction on first loop element.

Comment: For me this command works. Use the verbose paramter to check what copy-item is doing

Comment: Alright done it, Verbose confirmed what I thought, it doesn't automatically create folder with the name of first folder element and copies and dumps files right there, however it creates folders for following folder elements. Guess my OS is kinda whacked, need to deal with workaround i posted earlier.